# Improper std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator not detected at compilation time

Tags: c++, typechecking, allocator, compile-time-type-checking

I found that the `pmr::polymorphic_allocator` type seems to be not properly detected at compilation type.

I've the class (for example `MyClass`), what uses `pmr::polymorphic_allocator`, and this allocator has to be passed by constructor parameter:

```
// file MyClass.hpp
#include <memory_resource>

class Item
{
    // class members...
};

class MyClass
{
public:
    explicit MyClass(std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<Item> allocator)
    {
        // ....
    }

    // other members
};
```

Then, I'm trying to use my class:

```
#include "MyClass.hpp"
#include <memory_resource>

// this compiles w/out errors - as expected
auto myClass1 = MyClass(std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<Item>());

// and this compiles w/out errors too - as NOT expected
auto myClass2 = MyClass(std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<OtherType>());
```

Off course, the type `OtherType` is totally different than type `Item`.

So, I added some additional checks in constructor of `MyClass`:

```
// file MyClass.hpp
#include <memory_resource>
#include <type_traits>

class Item
{
    // class members...
};

class MyClass
{
public:
    explicit MyClass(std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<Item> allocator)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_same<Item, decltype(allocator)::value_type>::value,
            "Improper allocator!"); 
        // ....
    }

    // other members
};
```

... and the improper allocator is still not detected.
I can't find any reason for that. Any ideas?

My environment: GCC 10.2.0, CLion 2021.1

EDIT: ok, I found the reason.
The `pmr::polymorphic_allocator` has converting constructor, so there occurs the implicit conversion to the expected allocator:
[constructor description on cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/polymorphic_allocator/polymorphic_allocator).
So, it seems that there is no way to detect the usage of improper allocator.